# How to refresh a single element in a View?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a dynamic form and this is what I have:

Create.cshtml View

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <select id="SCat_Cat" name="SCat_Cat" asp-for="Cat_Id" asp-items="(SelectList)ViewBag.Cat_ID" class="form-control" onchange="funct()">
                <option value="0">Select Category</option>
            </select>
            <select id="SCat_SCat" name="SCat_SCat" asp-for="SCat_ID" asp-items="(SelectList)ViewBag.Scat_ID" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select Sub-Category</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Script that runs after selecting category:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function funct() {
        var catvalue = document.getElementById("SCat_Cat").value;
        alert(catvalue);
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '?CatID=' + catvalue,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        alert("Good");
                    }
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        return false;   
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string CatID)
        {

            ViewBag.Cat_ID = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name");
            if (CatID == null)
            {    
                ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList("");
            }
            else
            {
                List<SubCategory> AllSubCategories = _context.SubCategory.ToList();
                List<SubCategory> SelectedSubCategories = AllSubCategories.FindAll(a => a.SCat_Cat.Contains(CatID));
                ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList(SelectedSubCategories, "SCat_ID", "SCat_Name");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

So far that is the most successful thing I've came up with but it resets everything, including the CSS, The only correct thing this does is populate the dropbox with the things I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Create a static class with an extension method like this:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    private const string RequestedWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
    private const string XmlHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";

    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now modify your controller method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string CatID)
    {

        ViewBag.Cat_ID = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name");
        if (CatID == null)
        {    
            ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList("");
        }
        else
        {
            List<SubCategory> AllSubCategories = _context.SubCategory.ToList();
            List<SubCategory> SelectedSubCategories = AllSubCategories.FindAll(a => a.SCat_Cat.Contains(CatID));
            ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList(SelectedSubCategories, "SCat_ID", "SCat_Name");
        }
        return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (IActionResult)PartialView() : View();
    }
```

so you can only return a PartialView if the request is an ajax Request, and your js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function funct() {
    var catvalue = document.getElementById("SCat_Cat").value;
    alert(catvalue);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '?CatID=' + catvalue,
            success: function (result) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = result;
                alert("Good");
                
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    return false;   
}
```

For example you can insert your form in a div with id "myDiv".

Comment: Request.IsAjaxRequest "HttpRequest does not contain a definition for IsAjaxRequest" Am I missing something?

Comment: Try changing Request.IsAjaxRequest with
`new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest()` and add `using System.Web.Mvc;` `using System.Web;`

Comment: I added System.Web.Mvc and it just bricked everything. Doesn't recognize half the stuff in my controller now.

Comment: You're welcome, i will edit the answer so that it can be helpful for someone else. I would appreciate if you set the answer as accepted.